# Rspec: Could not parse for environment rp_env

Tags: rspec, puppet, rspec-puppet

I am new to rspec-puppet, and i am beginning with test writing:

I wrote this code:

```
describe 'rcjenkins' do
  let(:facts) do
    {
      :osfamily => 'RedHat'
    }
  end
  let(:pre_condition) do
    "$facts = #{facts}"
  end

  let(:params) do
    {
      :host => "127.0.0.1",
      :github_token => "valor",

    }
  end
  it do
    is_expected.to contain_class('rcjenkins::nginx')
  end
end
```

which should test:

```
class rcjenkins($host, $github_token) {
  include rcjenkins::package

  class { 'nginx': }

  nginx::resource::upstream { 'jenkins':
    members => [
      'localhost:8080'
    ]
  }

  nginx::resource::vhost { $host:
    proxy => 'http://jenkins'
  }

  nginx::resource::location { 'jenkins_root':
    ensure         => present,
    vhost          => $host,
    location       => '/status',
    location_alias => '/usr/share/nginx/html'
  }
```

This was more of a "test of the test", but things keep failing.
i am getting:

```
  1) rcjenkins Treco should contain Class[rcjenkins::nginx]
     Failure/Error: is_expected.to contain_class('rcjenkins::nginx')

     Puppet::ParseErrorWithIssue:
       Could not parse for environment rp_env: Syntax error at ':' at line 1:11 on node localhost.localdomain
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/pops/parser/parser_support.rb:127:in `on_error'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/pops/parser/lexer2.rb:712:in `scan'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/pops/parser/parser_support.rb:240:in `_parse'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/pops/parser/parser_support.rb:134:in `parse_string'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/pops/parser/evaluating_parser.rb:28:in `parse_string'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/e4_parser_adapter.rb:29:in `parse'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/node/environment.rb:507:in `perform_initial_import'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/node/environment.rb:247:in `known_resource_types'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:767:in `block in initvars'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/context.rb:65:in `override'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet.rb:293:in `override'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:765:in `initvars'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:422:in `initialize'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:33:in `new'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/parser/compiler.rb:33:in `compile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:266:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/util/profiler/around_profiler.rb:58:in `profile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/util/profiler.rb:51:in `profile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:264:in `block in compile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/util.rb:223:in `block in benchmark'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/util.rb:222:in `benchmark'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:262:in `compile'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/indirector/catalog/compiler.rb:53:in `find'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/puppet-4.9.2/lib/puppet/indirector/indirection.rb:194:in `find'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/adapters.rb:74:in `catalog'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/adapters.rb:148:in `catalog'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:203:in `build_catalog_without_cache'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:212:in `block in build_catalog'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/cache.rb:17:in `call'is_expected.to contain_class('rcjenkins::nginx')
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/cache.rb:17:in `get'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:211:in `build_catalog'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:30:in `block in load_catalogue'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:178:in `with_vardir'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:19:in `load_catalogue'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/example/class_example_group.rb:7:in `catalogue'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb:11:in `block in subject'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/matchers/create_generic.rb:82:in `call'
     # /home/luis.brandao/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/rspec-puppet-2.5.0/lib/rspec-puppet/matchers/create_generic.rb:82:in `matches?'
     # ./spec/classes/rcjenkins_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Line 39 is is_expected.to contain_class('rcjenkins::nginx'). Anyone know what is happening?

Edit:
I did also notice, that ANYTHING i change the test to, give me the same error. What i am missing? what is rp_env?

Comment: Besides the issue that Dominic Cleal brought up with your `let(:pre_condition)`, you are also focusing on the wrong part of the error message. The error message says `Syntax error at ':' at line 1:11 on node localhost.localdomain`. You have a syntax error somewhere else in code you did not post. That will solve your immediate issue.

Comment: Well, rspec-puppet generates a manifest that contains the `pre_condition` joined with a class declaration with the parameters given. The error's from that generated manifest rather than another file, as Puppet's not given a manifest path for the error. It's probably the `pre_condition` syntax.

Comment: @DominicCleal So it would then fail at the part of the manifest where he is defining a symbol hash key. Makes sense. Going to see how this question evolves, but it does seem like you nailed it so will upvote soon unless he discounts your theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP also asked about `rp_env`.

The environment `rp_env` stands for "Rspec-Puppet Environment" and is a fake value for the environment added by Rspec-puppet itself.

It is defined [here](https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet/blob/99fc83144ceb2c14ad5b5a9428b7ad57eca659ee/lib/rspec-puppet/support.rb#L14-L16) in the code.

If you wish to set the environment yourself in your Rspec-puppet code, there is a useful post [here](https://www.onyxpoint.com/setting-custom-environments-in-rspec-puppet-tests/) that explains how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Remove or fix your pre_condition, it isn't generating a valid Puppet manifest:

```
let(:pre_condition) do
  "$facts = #{facts}"
end
```

If the Ruby variable `facts` is `{ :osfamily => 'RedHat' }` then this generates a Puppet manifest like this:

```
$facts = {:osfamily=>'RedHat'}
```

The colon in front of the osfamily hash key isn't valid in a Puppet manifest (it would have to be a string, e.g. `'osfamily'`).

I don't think there's any reason to set `pre_condition` here, your `let(:facts)` ought to be sufficient.

Comment: Without that precondition, i keep getting "Evaluation Error: Operator '[]' is not applicable to an Undef Value"
ref: https://github.com/rodjek/rspec-puppet/issues/344

Comment: @Techmago That issue is an absolute lie. I use `let(:facts) {{ fact: 'fact_value' }}` all the time in RSpec Puppet and it populates the `$facts` hash. You and he are having some other issue here.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot reproduce that issue and it's been supported in rspec-puppet for over a year. If you can show more detail about your error (the source of the syntax error) when removing `pre_condition` by editing the question, we may be able to help further.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I am making testes for some puppet recipes someone-else made... and i started learning puppet from scratch last week. The tests are still broke, but for an entirely diferent reason now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303648/rspec-puppet-nested-fixtures

Comment: Well, looks like this was the correct theory. Good find.